# assets aren't loading on a page but loads on others? slug permalink conflict?

Tags: permalinks, urls, slug

Hi does anyone know what could be stopping the assets from loading on 1 page but loads successfully on others?

This is a really strange bug. I can't figure out why it's doing it and how to fix.

For example if I go to https://workingurl.co.uk/testing-this-elephant

The assets won't load (css, js & images), here's a screenshot of how it looks -

[image: assets not loading]

When I inspect the source and click on the img src the image loads fine. Same for all the CSS and JS files they load fine when visiting them directly.

If I were to change the page slug to https://workingurl.co.uk/testing-this-dog

The assets load fine.

I haven't got any categories or tags with the same slug name.

My .htaccess doesn't mention any of the words used in the slug that has issues.

I'm not sure what else to try. Can someone please advise?

Comment: it's hard to tell from the screenshot and info etc., but your screenshot seems to indicate that this is a 404 error page? Perhaps the assets aren't enqueued for 404 pages?

Comment: In the devtools network tab the page status is 404 and the assets 403.

If I deliberately go to a 404 page that doesn't exist, the WordPress 404 page template loads successfully with assets.